# Attribute matListItemTitle is not allowed here

Tags: angular, angular-material, webstorm

Trying to implement a list from Angular Material in an Angular application. WebStorm arises the message written in the title above.

I found out the issue [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000125610-how-to-fix-attribute-is-not-allowed-here-on-angular-project) but in this case I can't call `matListItemTitle` as a dynamic parameter (as described at the end of that post).

```html
<h3>Two line lists</h3>
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item>
    <span matListItemTitle>Title</span>
    <span matListItemLine>Second line</span>
  </mat-list-item>
  <mat-list-item>
    <span matListItemTitle>Title</span>
    <span>Second line</span>
  </mat-list-item>
  <mat-list-item>
    <span matListItemTitle>Title</span>
    Second line
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently had this same issue. In my case i was using an older version of [angular (14.2.7)](https://v14.material.angular.io/components/list/overview). According to the angular Component documentation the `matListItemTitle` and `matListItemLine` attributes were introduced in [angular 15](https://v15.material.angular.io/components/list/overview)

Notes:
Using Jetbrains Rider 2022.3.2

Comment: You are right, it was a matter of the version.